# Настройка автообновления страницы в браузере

Tags: html, css, netbeans, sass

Пишу стили в SCSS компилятся в Koala
Установил расширение для Crome NetBeans Connector
Что то похожее раньше ставил при сохранении обновляло, может быть я что то не настроил в Netbeans
Поставил ещё LifeReload в html сразу срабатывает, а в стилях нужно мышкой навести тогда обновляет

нашёл вот такой пример, но хотелось бы без костылей

```
var modTime = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  $.post("isModified.php", {"file":"main.css", "time":modTime}, function(rst) {
    if (rst.time != modTime) {
      modTime = rst.time;
      // reload style tag
      $("head link[rel='stylesheet']:eq(0)").remove();
      $("head").prepend($(document.createElement("link")).attr({
          "rel":"stylesheet",
          "href":"http://sstatic.net/mso/all.css?v=4372"
        })
      );
    }
  });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

А чем js не устраивает?

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ location.reload() }, 1000 )
```

каждую секунду будет обновлять. Если в сайт нельзя вставить, то можно расширение для chrome налабать быстренько...

Comment: зачем js если можно <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" > Вопрос другого характера был

Comment: `как настроить автообновление страницы в браузере` надо что бы на событие реогировал или в чём проблема тогда?

Comment: Да должен при ctrl+s  обновлять, тоесть сохраняется файл sass  он компилится получается css  после чего обновляется страница

Comment: ajax-ом забрать последнее время обновления css, если изменилось - reload()

Comment: это всё костыли есть нормальные рабочие решения